# WiFi Disappeared Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: wifi, drivers, internet

I have been using Linux Mint for the last month but suddenly my WiFi doesn't work anymore and is not showing. The stock Linux driver was working until a few days ago. My computer is an HP Pavilion g6 laptop.

Comment: What is output of `ip l` and `lsmod` as well as `lspci -vv`? What's your Wi-Fi chip?

Answer (score 0):

the linux driver was corrupted some how and need to be re-installed